# animate and resetting interval

Tags: jquery

I am a bit new at jquery and need some help, i searched the net for a solution and tried to edit it to meet my requirement. what i wanted is a change background event and there also a slider inside content and when changing the controls, the background also change. I've done it but I had 2 problems:

1. I need to reset the interval when its clicked (now its mixing it
   up)
2. I need to animate the change in the background insted of
       changing directly (ease or fade)

here is the code:-

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var images = ['images/background/body-bg.jpg','images/background/body-bg2.jpg'];
    var i = 0;

    function changeBackground() {
        $('html').css({
            'background': function(){
                             if (i >= images.length) {
                                i=0;
                            }
                            return 'url(' + images[i++] + ')';

                        },
            'background-position':'center',
            'background-attachment':'fixed',
            'background-size':'cover'
        })
    }

    // Call it on the first time
    changeBackground();

    (function(){
        $('.sliderControl > li').children().on('click', function(){
            changeBackground();
            window.clearInterval()
        })
    })();

    // Set an interval to continue
    setInterval(changeBackground, 5000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

using js tween library you acheive this easily

http://www.jstween.org/

```
                          {
            id: "JSframe1",
            //audio: "<filename and path, without extension>",
            play: function(JQtarget, FNcallback) {
                JQtarget.find(".JSimage1").tween({



                        transform:{
                            start: 'rotate(0deg) scale( 1 )',
                            stop: 'rotate(360deg) scale( 1 )',
                            time: 0,
                            duration: 1,
                            effect:'linear'
                            },
                            width: {
                            start: 1,
                            stop: 100,
                            time: 0,
                            duration: 1,
                            units: '%'

                            },
                            height: {
                            start: 1,
                            stop: 100,
                            time: 0,
                            duration: 1,
                            units: '%'
                            },


                });
                setTimeout(FNcallback, 7000);
                $.play();
            }
        },
```